# Problem with omitting extra information when importing a value in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, omittag

I want to make a DataFrame from data of another Dataframe. my first table has 3 columns and I chose the min value of one of the columns and I want to choose two other corresponding value and put it on another DataFrame. but when I import it I get extra information that won't let me convert it to float64. what should I do?

`a= fp['w']`
`b= fp[r'$\Omega_m$']`
`data={"best_value_w": [a], "best_value_$\Omega$": [b], "errors":[1]}`

`bv_table= pd.DataFrame(data, index=['1"$\sigma$"', '2"$\sigma$"',  '3"$\sigma$"'])`

[here is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8lhA.png)

but I want something like this, but without brackets, I want dtype to be float, not object

[what I almost want but without brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLKLv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I should use astype like this :

`bv_table[' best_value_w ']=bv_table.best_value_w.astype(float)`

`bv_table[' best_value_$\Omega$ ']=bv_table.best_value_omega.astype(float)`

then I got a table like this:

[Done!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hrqI.png)